# Unable to validate the following destination configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to enable Eventbridge notification on S3 but I am getting this error message "Unable to validate the following destination configurations
"
I am not sure what's causing this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have an issue with the SNS access policy. There is a video of troubleshooting this issue at https://youtu.be/RjSW75YsBMM.

Answer (score 15):

Make sure that your SNS topic has the proper Access Policy set. In my case, the default Access Policy included an `AWS:SourceOwner` condition which I needed to remove in order to allow the S3 event configuration to perform the `SNS:Publish` action against the topic.

Comment: Had the same issue , resolved with your quick fix

Comment: +1. Example in the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-access-policy-use-cases.html#sns-allow-s3-bucket-to-publish-to-topic

Answer (score 1):

I my case, I just modified the below under the SNS Topic > Access policy. And it works

From: "**AWS:SourceOwner": "1234123412**"
To: "**AWS:SourceAccount": "1234123412**".

If that didn't work out, please add below as well under the same access policy after the AWS:SourceAccount.

"ArnLike": {
"AWS:SourceArn": "**YOUR_S3_BUCKET_ARN**"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).